# Obtain styled attributes for child from parent's style definition

Tags: android, xml, attr

The question title is probably nonsensical. I am creating a bunch of custom views that will be placed in a single parent layout - a custom `FrameLayout`.

These custom views have their own style attr which are set using the parent's style attr.

As an example, consider `Parent` to be the custom `FrameLayout`. Its style `attr` is defined in `attrs.xml`:

```
<attr name="parentStyleAttr" format="reference" />
```

The `Child` also has its attr:

```
<attr name="childStyleAttr" format="reference" />
```

And `Parent` defines its styleable attr as:

```
<declare-styleable name="Parent">
    <attr name="childStyleAttr" />
</declare-styleable>
```

`Child's` styleable attr:

```
<declare-styleable name="Child">
    <attr name="childBgColor" format="color" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Following this, I define a style for the parent:

```
<style name="ParentStyle">
    <item name="childStyleAttr">@style/ChildStyle</item>
</style>
```

and one for `Child`:

```
<style name="ChildStyle">
    <item name="childBgColor">@color/blah</item>
</style>
```

For `Parent`, I set up `parentStyleAttr` in the app's theme:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="parentStyleAttr">@style/ParentStyle</item>
</style>
```

Now, when `Parent` is created, it inflates a layout containing `Child`:

```
LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.child, this, true);
```

During `Child's` initialization, I need to read the value of the style attribute set in `@style/ChildStyle` - `childBgColor`.

This doesn't work:

```
final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
          R.styleable.Child, R.attr.childStyleAttr, R.style.ChildStyle);
```

The way I am currently reading `attr/childBgColor` is:

```
public Child(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(createThemeWrapper(context), attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initialize(attrs, defStyleAttr, R.style.ChildStyle);
}

private static ContextThemeWrapper createThemeWrapper(Context context) {
    final TypedArray forParent = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            new int[]{ R.attr.parentStyleAttr });
    int parentStyle = forParent.getResourceId(0, R.style.ParentStyle);
    forParent.recycle();

    TypedArray forChild = context.obtainStyledAttributes(parentStyle,
            new int[]{ R.attr.childStyleAttr });
    int childStyleId = forChild.getResourceId(0, R.style.ChildStyle);
    forChild.recycle();

    return new ContextThemeWrapper(context, childStyleId);
}

void initialize(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    Context context = getContext();
    final Resources res = getResources();

    final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Child);

    ....
}
```

I am not confident if this is the right approach. Can someone help shed some some light on this?

Comment: your code isn't working or just want to improve it?

Comment: @NikMyers I want to know if my current approach is correct. And if it isn't, what is the right approach?

Comment: I may get it wrong, but the problem you're describing sounds like parent theme inheritance that has been implemented in the recent `appcompat` update: https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/#androidtheme The author mentioned `LayoutInflater.Factory2` as the class that enables parent theme inheritance.

Comment: Would it not be simpler to read the xml attributes in a child and make getters?

Comment: @BojanKseneman I'm afraid I don't follow. `Would it not be simpler to read the xml attributes in a child...` This is what I am trying to do. To make things clearer, I can initialize `childStyleAttr` under `AppTheme` and read `childBgColor` just fine. But if I go with this, I'll have to initialize style attributes for _all_ children under `AppTheme`. Instead, I want to set `parentStyleAttr` which should handle style-attributes for all children.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the simple solution which extending the Layout and create a custom layout that sends it attributes to it's children [while adding them](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/view/ViewGroup.java#3317)

Comment: You have linked to `addViewInLayout(View child, int index, LayoutParams params, boolean preventRequestLayout)`. How should I use this to read style attrs for the `Child`?

Comment: by overriding this method you will have access to each child been added so that you will be able to insert the attrs you want programatically

Comment: Sorry, but I am not looking for alternatives. In accordance with android guidelines, styling info should be set using attributes. Otherwise, there's no purpose of styles, attrs etc. since everything _can be_ done on Java side.